# Pressed state for RecyclerView Item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using horizontal recyclerview as a custom bottom navigation bar. I want to define a pressed state for the each item so their color can change.

I tried to do it like this but couldn't manage it

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/menu_pressed" android:state_activated="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/menu_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/menu_pressed" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/menu_pressed" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/menu" />
</selector>
```

recycler view:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_selector"
        android:fadingEdge="vertical|horizontal"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="60dp"
        android:fillViewport="false"
        android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal|vertical"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
```

Comment: try giving state pressed background to listItem and remove 
`android:clickable="true"
 android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true" `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a RecyclerView you cant define and set a single selector for every item like we could with ListView. It has to be done at the viewholder level.

So each item layout has to have a selector set as a background.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_selector">
```

Then in your adapter `onBind` you can set a click listener and it should work

```
holder.frame.setOnClickListener {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: this changes the background color when I click but I have to click twice to make onclicklistener do the job?

Comment: you should not have to click twice, if you set a click listener to the FrameLayout or root view. one time should be enough

Comment: I have an interface called "MenuClickListener" where I pass menu item and their id, I implement it in my activity

Comment: If you use something like holder.itemView.setOnClickListener maybe you can remove the android:clickable="true" tag

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can use "BottomNavigationBar" it is an android widget for better implementation. 
Even if you want to use recyclerView for the same implementation then please use these attributes in the RecyclerView item instead of recyclerView itself.

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: you are using some custom adapter and inflating some view there, put these elements in that view